# datetime error when setting filter to current financial year (01July2013 - 30June2014)

Tags: sql, datetime

a sql script that we written last year has stopped working now that we in the year 2014 with the following error "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value"

I'm not familiar with SQL, the error message is pointing to this section of the script.

```
declare @current_fiscal datetime

set     @current_fiscal =
case
when    (month(getdate()) < 7) then
cast(dateadd(year,-1,year(getdate())) as varchar(4)) + '0702'
else
cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(4)) +'0702'
end
```

---

I'm not sure what the purpose of '0702' is also. Look forward to hearing from someone.

Answer (score 4):

They obviously wrote this in July or later and never tested the first half of the expression.

```
cast(dateadd(year,-1,year(getdate())) as varchar(4)) + '0702'
```

Should be:

```
cast(year(dateadd(year,-1,getdate())) as varchar(4)) + '0702'
```

Or even easier:

```
CAST(YEAR(GETDATE())-1) AS CHAR(4))
```

As an aside, with a little debugging 101, you could have discovered the issue for yourself immediately:

```
DECLARE @current_fiscal VARCHAR(32);
SET @current_fiscal = cast(dateadd(year,-1,year(getdate())) as varchar(4)) + '0702';
PRINT @current_fiscal;
```

Result:

```
--------
Jul 0702
```

Now, why is it doing that, you might ask? Let's inspect each part of the expression:

```
YEAR(GETDATE()) = 2014
DATEADD(YEAR,-1,2014) actually turns 2014 into a date, which is:
DATEADD(DAY, 2014, '19000101') = '1904-07-08'
Now, subtract a year from that, you get '1903-07-08'
Now, cast that as a varchar(32) without a style, you get:
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), CONVERT(DATETIME,'1903-07-08'));
Which is Jul  8 1903 12:00AM
The first 4 characters are Jul and a space.
```

Comment: I'm assuming OP didn't write this at all.

Comment: @Zane that's why I said "they" :-)

Comment: Much appreciate the reply Aaron. I suppose I need a lot more practice in understanding how dates work cause i still dont understand how did the  '19000101') = '1904-07-08' section come into the picture ?

Comment: @user3168913 I was trying to explain how your date calculation ended on the wrong date. You were adding days to a number (2014), not a date. That number is interpreted as that many days after 1900-01-01.

Answer (score 0):

They screwed up the order of the function calls for pre-July.  Given the level of this code, I suspect you're going to find other issues down the road.  This should work, though:

```
declare @current_fiscal datetime 
set @current_fiscal = case when (month(getdate()) < 7) then cast(year(dateadd(year,-1,getdate())) as varchar(4)) + '0702' else cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(4)) +'0702' end
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, been snowed under and eager to test this out. Man-o-man cant believe it was that simple, it worked first shot. :) You are awesome Joe! Little concerned I might have other issues, I suppose I'll tackle those when they happen. Thanks again!